# How to interpret /proc/pid/maps for pidgin application

Tags: process

```
08048000-08109000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8610955    /usr/bin/pidgin
08109000-0810c000 rw-p 000c1000 08:01 8610955    /usr/bin/pidgin
09686000-09f4c000 rw-p 09686000 00:00 0          [heap]
b46b7000-b46b9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10316414   /usr/lib/gconv/CP1250.so
b46b9000-b46ba000 r--p 00001000 08:01 10316414   /usr/lib/gconv/CP1250.so
b46ba000-b46bb000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 10316414   /usr/lib/gconv/CP1250.so
b46bb000-b4703000 rw-p b46bb000 00:00 0 
b4703000-b5152000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10855144   /usr/share/fonts/TTF/wqy-zenhei.ttf
b5152000-b58a8000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10858251   /usr/share/fonts/TTF/sazanami-gothic.ttf
b58a8000-b58aa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10707102   /usr/lib/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-hangul-fc.so
b58aa000-b58ab000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 10707102   /usr/lib/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-hangul-fc.so
b58ab000-b58ad000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10707101   /usr/lib/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-arabic-fc.so
b58ad000-b58ae000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 10707101   /usr/lib/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-arabic-fc.so
b58ae000-b58af000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10707100   /usr/lib/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-arabic-lang.so
b58af000-b58b0000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 10707100   /usr/lib/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-arabic-lang.so
b58b0000-b58e7000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10314811   /usr/share/icons/hicolor/icon-theme.cache
b58e7000-b5947000 rw-s 00000000 00:08 131073     /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
b5947000-b5f5f000 rw-p b5947000 00:00 0 
b5f5f000-b5feb000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10856177   /usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
b5feb000-b6603000 rw-p b5feb000 00:00 0 
b6603000-b669b000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10856178   /usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSans.ttf
b669b000-b66ab000 r--s 00000000 08:01 11397515   /var/cache/fontconfig/8d4af663993b81a124ee82e610bb31f9-x86.cache-2
b66ab000-b66b5000 r--s 00000000 08:01 11395119   /var/cache/fontconfig/d62e99ef547d1d24cdb1bd22ec1a2976-x86.cache-2
b66b5000-b66cd000 r--s 00000000 08:01 11397344   /var/cache/fontconfig/f6b893a7224233d96cb72fd88691c0b4-x86.cache-2
b66cd000-b66d2000 r--s 00000000 08:01 11395090   /var/cache/fontconfig/f349e9996a5320f6dd491cedd2b1f964-x86.cache-2
b66d2000-b66e5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913299   /usr/lib/purple-2/libzephyr.so
b66e5000-b66e7000 rw-p 00012000 08:01 10913299   /usr/lib/purple-2/libzephyr.so
b66e7000-b66e9000 rw-p b66e7000 00:00 0 
b66e9000-b6713000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913344   /usr/lib/purple-2/libqq.so
b6713000-b6714000 rw-p 0002a000 08:01 10913344   /usr/lib/purple-2/libqq.so
b6714000-b6779000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512393    /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.11.4.3
b6779000-b677b000 rw-p 00065000 08:01 8512393    /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.11.4.3
b677b000-b6816000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8511792    /usr/lib/libgnutls.so.26.11.3
b6816000-b681c000 rw-p 0009b000 08:01 8511792    /usr/lib/libgnutls.so.26.11.3
b681c000-b681e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10707103   /usr/lib/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
b681e000-b681f000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 10707103   /usr/lib/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
b681f000-b6830000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10675625   /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libubuntulooks.so
b6830000-b6831000 rw-p 00011000 08:01 10675625   /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libubuntulooks.so
b6831000-b6992000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913301   /usr/lib/purple-2/perl.so
b6992000-b6994000 rw-p 00161000 08:01 10913301   /usr/lib/purple-2/perl.so
b6994000-b69a5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512535    /usr/lib/libXft.so.2.1.13
b69a5000-b69a6000 rw-p 00010000 08:01 8512535    /usr/lib/libXft.so.2.1.13
b69a6000-b6aa1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512492    /usr/lib/libtk8.5.so
b6aa1000-b6ab2000 rw-p 000fa000 08:01 8512492    /usr/lib/libtk8.5.so
b6ab2000-b6b9d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8513009    /usr/lib/libtcl8.5.so
b6b9d000-b6ba3000 rw-p 000eb000 08:01 8513009    /usr/lib/libtcl8.5.so
b6ba3000-b6ba7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10674979   /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
b6ba7000-b6ba8000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 10674979   /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
b6ba8000-b6baa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913349   /usr/lib/purple-2/statenotify.so
b6baa000-b6bab000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 10913349   /usr/lib/purple-2/statenotify.so
b6bab000-b6bae000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512398    /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0.4.0
b6bae000-b6baf000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 8512398    /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0.4.0
b6baf000-b6bb3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913357   /usr/lib/purple-2/ssl-gnutls.so
b6bb3000-b6bb4000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 10913357   /usr/lib/purple-2/ssl-gnutls.so
b6bb4000-b6bb5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913354   /usr/lib/purple-2/libaim.so
b6bb5000-b6bb6000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 10913354   /usr/lib/purple-2/libaim.so
b6bb6000-b6bb7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913296   /usr/lib/purple-2/ssl.so
b6bb7000-b6bb8000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 10913296   /usr/lib/purple-2/ssl.so
b6bb8000-b6bc5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913300   /usr/lib/purple-2/tcl.so
b6bc5000-b6bc6000 rw-p 0000d000 08:01 10913300   /usr/lib/purple-2/tcl.so
b6bc6000-b6bc7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913341   /usr/lib/purple-2/buddynote.so
b6bc7000-b6bc8000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 10913341   /usr/lib/purple-2/buddynote.so
b6bc8000-b6be0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913262   /usr/lib/purple-2/libnovell.so
b6be0000-b6be1000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 10913262   /usr/lib/purple-2/libnovell.so
b6be1000-b6be2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913352   /usr/lib/purple-2/newline.so
b6be2000-b6be3000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 10913352   /usr/lib/purple-2/newline.so
b6be3000-b6be5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913353   /usr/lib/purple-2/autoaccept.so
b6be5000-b6be6000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 10913353   /usr/lib/purple-2/autoaccept.so
b6be6000-b6c23000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913342   /usr/lib/purple-2/libmsn.so
b6c23000-b6c24000 rw-p 0003d000 08:01 10913342   /usr/lib/purple-2/libmsn.so
b6c24000-b6c28000 rw-p b6c24000 00:00 0 
b6c28000-b6c30000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913298   /usr/lib/purple-2/log_reader.so
b6c30000-b6c31000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 10913298   /usr/lib/purple-2/log_reader.so
b6c31000-b6c4e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913356   /usr/lib/purple-2/libgg.so
b6c4e000-b6c4f000 rw-p 0001d000 08:01 10913356   /usr/lib/purple-2/libgg.so
b6c4f000-b6c61000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913297   /usr/lib/purple-2/libirc.so
b6c61000-b6c62000 rw-p 00012000 08:01 10913297   /usr/lib/purple-2/libirc.so
b6c62000-b6c77000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913347   /usr/lib/purple-2/libmyspace.so
b6c77000-b6c78000 rw-p 00014000 08:01 10913347   /usr/lib/purple-2/libmyspace.so
b6c78000-b6c79000 rw-p b6c78000 00:00 0 
b6c79000-b6cb6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913292   /usr/lib/purple-2/liboscar.so.0.0.0
b6cb6000-b6cb8000 rw-p 0003c000 08:01 10913292   /usr/lib/purple-2/liboscar.so.0.0.0
b6cb8000-b6ddd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512891    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
b6ddd000-b6df2000 rw-p 00125000 08:01 8512891    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
b6df2000-b6df5000 rw-p b6df2000 00:00 0 

 (...)

b71fd000-b71fe000 rw-p b71fd000 00:00 0 
b71fe000-b7232000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512910    /usr/lib/libpixman-1.so.0.12.0
b7232000-b7233000 rw-p 00034000 08:01 8512910    /usr/lib/libpixman-1.so.0.12.0
b7233000-b726d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512644    /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0.1.2.32
b726d000-b726e000 rw-p 0003a000 08:01 8512644    /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0.1.2.32
b726e000-b72da000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10307580   /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6.3.18
b72da000-b72de000 rw-p 0006c000 08:01 10307580   /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6.3.18
b72de000-b7304000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512896    /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.2002.3
b7304000-b7305000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 8512896    /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.2002.3
b7305000-b7306000 rw-p b7305000 00:00 0 
b7306000-b730e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512574    /usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
b730e000-b730f000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 8512574    /usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
b730f000-b7314000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512539    /usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2.1.0
b7314000-b7315000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 8512539    /usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2.1.0
b7315000-b731c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512610    /usr/lib/libXi.so.6.0.0
b731c000-b731d000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 8512610    /usr/lib/libXi.so.6.0.0
b731d000-b731f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512615    /usr/lib/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
b731f000-b7320000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 8512615    /usr/lib/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
b7320000-b7327000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512646    /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1.3.0
b7327000-b7328000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 8512646    /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1.3.0
b7328000-b7329000 rw-p b7328000 00:00 0 
b7329000-b7351000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10307575   /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1.3.0
b7351000-b7352000 rw-p 00028000 08:01 10307575   /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1.3.0
b7352000-b7356000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512594    /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
b7356000-b7357000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 8512594    /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
b7357000-b7359000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512578    /usr/lib/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
b7359000-b735a000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 8512578    /usr/lib/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
b735a000-b735c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512571    /usr/lib/libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
b735c000-b735d000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 8512571    /usr/lib/libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
b735d000-b7370000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10305617   /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
b7370000-b7371000 rw-p 00012000 08:01 10305617   /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
b7371000-b7372000 rw-p b7371000 00:00 0 
b7372000-b737a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512486    /usr/lib/libenchant.so.1.4.2
b737a000-b737b000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 8512486    /usr/lib/libenchant.so.1.4.2
b737b000-b737d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512388    /usr/lib/libXau.so.6.0.0
b737d000-b737e000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 8512388    /usr/lib/libXau.so.6.0.0
b737e000-b7394000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512748    /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.0.0
b7394000-b7395000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 8512748    /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.0.0
b7395000-b7396000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512754    /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0.0.0
b7396000-b7397000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 8512754    /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0.0.0
b7397000-b73bb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7947610    /lib/libm-2.7.so
b73bb000-b73bc000 r--p 00023000 08:01 7947610    /lib/libm-2.7.so
b73bc000-b73bd000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 7947610    /lib/libm-2.7.so
b73bd000-b73be000 rw-p b73bd000 00:00 0 
b73be000-b7503000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7947648    /lib/libc-2.7.so
b7503000-b7504000 ---p 00145000 08:01 7947648    /lib/libc-2.7.so
b7504000-b7506000 r--p 00145000 08:01 7947648    /lib/libc-2.7.so
b7506000-b7507000 rw-p 00147000 08:01 7947648    /lib/libc-2.7.so
b7507000-b750a000 rw-p b7507000 00:00 0 
b750a000-b7519000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7947617    /lib/libresolv-2.7.so
b7519000-b751a000 r--p 0000f000 08:01 7947617    /lib/libresolv-2.7.so
b751a000-b751b000 rw-p 00010000 08:01 7947617    /lib/libresolv-2.7.so
b751b000-b751d000 rw-p b751b000 00:00 0 
b751d000-b7531000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7947650    /lib/libnsl-2.7.so
b7531000-b7532000 r--p 00013000 08:01 7947650    /lib/libnsl-2.7.so
b7532000-b7533000 rw-p 00014000 08:01 7947650    /lib/libnsl-2.7.so
b7533000-b7535000 rw-p b7533000 00:00 0 
b7535000-b7548000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7947616    /lib/libpthread-2.7.so
b7548000-b7549000 r--p 00012000 08:01 7947616    /lib/libpthread-2.7.so
b7549000-b754a000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 7947616    /lib/libpthread-2.7.so
b754a000-b754c000 rw-p b754a000 00:00 0 
b754c000-b754e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7947619    /lib/libutil-2.7.so
b754e000-b754f000 r--p 00001000 08:01 7947619    /lib/libutil-2.7.so
b754f000-b7550000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 7947619    /lib/libutil-2.7.so
b7550000-b761c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512901    /usr/lib/libpurple.so.0.5.2
b761c000-b7621000 rw-p 000cb000 08:01 8512901    /usr/lib/libpurple.so.0.5.2
b7621000-b7624000 rw-p b7621000 00:00 0 
b7624000-b76ef000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10312819   /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.1600.6
b76ef000-b76f0000 rw-p 000cb000 08:01 10312819   /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.1600.6
b76f0000-b76f1000 rw-p b76f0000 00:00 0 
b76f1000-b76f3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7947649    /lib/libdl-2.7.so
b76f3000-b76f4000 r--p 00001000 08:01 7947649    /lib/libdl-2.7.so
b76f4000-b76f5000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 7947649    /lib/libdl-2.7.so
b76f5000-b76f7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10312821   /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.1600.6
b76f7000-b76f8000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 10312821   /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.1600.6
b76f8000-b7731000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10312824   /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.1600.6
b7731000-b7732000 rw-p 00039000 08:01 10312824   /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.1600.6
b7732000-b7790000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512997    /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2.17.5
b7790000-b7792000 rw-p 0005e000 08:01 8512997    /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2.17.5
b7792000-b77cc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512894    /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0.2002.3
b77cc000-b77ce000 rw-p 00039000 08:01 8512894    /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0.2002.3
b77ce000-b77d6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512893    /usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.2002.3
b77d6000-b77d7000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 8512893    /usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.2002.3
b77d7000-b77d8000 rw-p b77d7000 00:00 0 
b77d8000-b77ee000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8511815    /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.1200.12
b77ee000-b77ef000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 8511815    /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.1200.12
b77ef000-b7806000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8511632    /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0.2314.1
b7806000-b7808000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 8511632    /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0.2314.1
b7808000-b7887000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8511814    /usr/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.1200.12
b7887000-b788a000 rw-p 0007f000 08:01 8511814    /usr/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.1200.12
b788a000-b7be9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8511810    /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.1200.12
b7be9000-b7bef000 rw-p 0035f000 08:01 8511810    /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.1200.12
b7bef000-b7bf0000 rw-p b7bef000 00:00 0 
b7bf0000-b7d05000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512800    /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.6.32
b7d05000-b7d0a000 rw-p 00115000 08:01 8512800    /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.6.32
b7d0a000-b7d0c000 rw-p b7d0a000 00:00 0 
b7d0c000-b7d13000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512271    /usr/lib/libstartup-notification-1.so.0.0.0
b7d13000-b7d14000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 8512271    /usr/lib/libstartup-notification-1.so.0.0.0
b7d14000-b7d19000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512183    /usr/lib/libgtkspell.so.0.0.0
b7d19000-b7d1a000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 8512183    /usr/lib/libgtkspell.so.0.0.0
b7d1a000-b7d2e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512527    /usr/lib/libICE.so.6.3.0
b7d2e000-b7d30000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 8512527    /usr/lib/libICE.so.6.3.0
b7d30000-b7d31000 rw-p b7d30000 00:00 0 
b7d31000-b7d38000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512531    /usr/lib/libSM.so.6.0.0
b7d38000-b7d39000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 8512531    /usr/lib/libSM.so.6.0.0
b7d39000-b7d3b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512543    /usr/lib/libXss.so.1.0.0
b7d3b000-b7d3c000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 8512543    /usr/lib/libXss.so.1.0.0
b7d3c000-b7d49000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512590    /usr/lib/libXext.so.6.4.0
b7d49000-b7d4a000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 8512590    /usr/lib/libXext.so.6.4.0
b7d4a000-b7d4b000 rw-p b7d4a000 00:00 0 
b7d4b000-b7e2e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8512367    /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.2.0
b7e2e000-b7e31000 rw-p 000e3000 08:01 8512367    /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.2.0
b7e31000-b7e32000 rw-p b7e31000 00:00 0 
b7e32000-b7e39000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7947618    /lib/librt-2.7.so
b7e39000-b7e3a000 r--p 00006000 08:01 7947618    /lib/librt-2.7.so
b7e3a000-b7e3b000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 7947618    /lib/librt-2.7.so
b7e3b000-b7e3e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10312823   /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0.1600.6
b7e3e000-b7e3f000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 10312823   /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0.1600.6
b7e3f000-b7ebd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8511645    /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0.18.0
b7ebd000-b7ec1000 rw-p 0007e000 08:01 8511645    /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0.18.0
b7ec1000-b7ef6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10307057   /usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3.4.0
b7ef6000-b7ef7000 r--p 00034000 08:01 10307057   /usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3.4.0
b7ef7000-b7ef8000 rw-p 00035000 08:01 10307057   /usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3.4.0
b7ef8000-b7f13000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10307072   /usr/lib/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.1.0
b7f13000-b7f14000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 10307072   /usr/lib/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.1.0
b7f14000-b7f15000 rw-p b7f14000 00:00 0 
b7f15000-b7f16000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913373   /usr/lib/pidgin/iconaway.so
b7f16000-b7f17000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 10913373   /usr/lib/pidgin/iconaway.so
b7f17000-b7f19000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913358   /usr/lib/pidgin/timestamp.so
b7f19000-b7f1a000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 10913358   /usr/lib/pidgin/timestamp.so
b7f1a000-b7f1c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10913359   /usr/lib/pidgin/history.so
b7f1c000-b7f1d000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 10913359   /usr/lib/pidgin/history.so
b7f1d000-b7f1e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10315686   /usr/lib/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
b7f1e000-b7f1f000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10315686   /usr/lib/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
b7f1f000-b7f20000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 10315686   /usr/lib/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
b7f20000-b7f21000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10642878   /usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_NUMERIC
b7f21000-b7f22000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10651074   /usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_TIME
b7f22000-b7f23000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10651075   /usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_MONETARY
b7f23000-b7f24000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10660548   /usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES
b7f24000-b7f25000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10651184   /usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_PAPER
b7f25000-b7f26000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10651181   /usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_NAME
b7f26000-b7f27000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10651073   /usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_ADDRESS
b7f27000-b7f28000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10651182   /usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_TELEPHONE
b7f28000-b7f29000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10651185   /usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_MEASUREMENT
b7f29000-b7f2a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 10651080   /usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_IDENTIFICATION
b7f2a000-b7f2b000 r-xp b7f2a000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7f2b000-b7f47000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7947672    /lib/ld-2.7.so
b7f47000-b7f48000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 7947672    /lib/ld-2.7.so
b7f48000-b7f49000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 7947672    /lib/ld-2.7.so
bfc32000-bfc47000 rwxp bffea000 00:00 0          [stack]
bfc47000-bfc48000 rw-p bffff000 00:00 0
```

This is the output of `cat /proc/pid/maps` where pid is the process id for pidgin process. Here i can see the address range of `stack`, `heap`. But what is `vdso` and what are other lines for?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [/proc man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) the output of /proc/pid/maps will looks like :

```
address           perms offset  dev   inode   pathname
08048000-08056000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
```

Where :

- **`address`** is the address space in the process that it occupies
- **`perms`** is a set of permissions :

  r = read
  w = write
  x = execute
  s = shared
  p = private (copy on write)
- **`offset`** is the offset into the file/whatever
- **`dev`** is the device (major:minor)
- **`inode`** is the inode on that device. 0 indicates that no inode is associated with the memory region, as the case would be with BSS (uninitialized data).
- **`pathname`** if the region was mapped from a file, this is the name of the file. This field is blank for anonymous mapped regions.

  In the **pathname** field, there can be other funny things :

  - `[heap]` is the address of the process's heap
  - `[stack]` is the address of the process's stack
  - `[vdso]` stands for virtual dynamic shared object. It's used by system calls to switch to kernel mode ([detailed article about it](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/)).